# Cannot modify content of iframe, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to modify content of an iframe but it does not work.

This is my main.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Main page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Main page</h3>
<iframe src="ifr.htm" id="ifr" name="ifr"></iframe>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ifr').load(function(){
        $('#ifr').contents().find('body').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>!    Yay!!!');
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

This is my ifr.htm

```
<html>
<head><title>Iframe page</title></head>
<body>
 Content to be displayed in iframe ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An iframe is independent of the frame that is displaying it. To apply changes (styles / content / etc.) to the iFrame page you need to edit that page.

If you did edit that page but are not seeing the changes, you probably just need to clear the cache for that page. Visit the iframe page directly and hit refresh until you see the change

Comment: can you elaborate on `does not work`? do you get any errors?

Comment: [It's working here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/HuuMZ/1/), content is being changed.

Comment: @SheikhHeera that is only working because the initial load of the iframe failed (404)

Comment: The file loaded in the `iframe` is `ifr.htm` but the file is named `ifr.html`.

Comment: @jbabey you are right, it is working cause of the 404 error

Comment: Hi, my ifr is named as htm.. its an typo in stackoverflow, edited it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please don't forget the `cross-domain` policy, otherwise it won't work.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/wTWjF/

*(Just to know, I am not using a 404 page, take a look)*

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ifr').ready(function(){
        $(this).contents().find('body').html('Hey, I have changed the body content yay!');
    });
});​
```

Comment: I tried the example, and it doesnt function anymore. The jsfiddle you included just shows an iframe with a 404 in it.

I dont see that message in the document anywhere in the iframe that says "I have changed the body content"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are honoring the cross-domain policy, this sounds like a timing issue. Chances are your iframe has already finished loading when the `document.ready` of the parent page fires.

You could try changing your `frame.load` to `frame.ready` as `.ready` will fire immediately if it is bound after the ready event has already triggered.

Comment: something is going really weird, i copy/paste the exact code and it couldnt work, however it work in jsfiddle.. any insights?

Comment: @Slay if you are running in IE i know the iframe has a `readyState` property you can interrogate. i'm not sure if the other major browsers support this property, though.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

You set the `src` attribute of your `iFrame` to a blank page (blank.htm) or "", then in the ready handler you change the src to **ifr.htm**.

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#ifr').load(function(){
        $(this).contents().find('body').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>!    Yay!!!');
    });
    $('#ifr').attr("src", "ifr.htm");
});
```