# Can't use document.write to write in head

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change content of iframe without src. So i try

```
var doc = findIframe().get(0).contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(GM_getResourceText('iframe.html'));
    doc.close();
```

Where content of iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>iframe</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">some style</style>
        <script> some script</script>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But all elemets instead of iframe head appends to iframe body. I execute script from main window. How it can be solved?

Comment: When you say "content of iframe" do you mean the current contents before you try and overwrite it, or do you mean the contents of iframe.html? What is findIframe()? When you say "append to body", body of what? The iframe? The containing frame? When are you executing your script and where are you executing it from? Please be clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong

Comment: Are you sure your code is executing AFTER the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Might be unrelated to your problem but I don't think you can choose a DOCTYPE with `document.write()`. Apart from that, you suggest you cannot just change the `src` attribute of your `<iframe>` tag; it'd possibly help to know the exact reason.

Comment: @Joren Yes, and same origin policy is also not a problem. I just dont understand why i have all elements(script,css) in head but after doc.write they appear in body

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Try to delete DOCTYPE but it did't help