# How to remove rel stylesheet attribute or modify it's effect from external iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So here is the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/example.php"></iframe>
```

and the output of it

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="http://example.com/css/style.css" type='text/css' />


<div id="someid" class="someclass">
some random text....
</div>
```

Now how can i control this html div given that i don't own example.com?

How can i add css from my website to modify this div?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .header{display:none;}  </style>"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: A similar thread is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong

Comment: You can't. Cross domain policy.