# How to clear an iframe of all content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using an iframe and dynmically loading its content from an API. I'm trying to find a way to clear the iframe of all of it's content without changeing the src attribute. E.G.

```
<iframe class="bla" src="//blabla">
  <html>
     Lots of HTML rendered
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Needs to become:

```
<iframe class="bla" src="//blabla"></iframe>
```

Very important that I keep all of the iframe attributes.
Is there a way to do this with javascript or jquery?

Comment: If it's not from the same origin, you generally can't edit the markup inside it.

Comment: Why is keeping the `src` attribute as is important in this scenario? If that wasn’t a requirement, you could simply set it to `about:blank`.

Comment: I'm trying to not have to rerun all the logic I used for getting the attributes, just to empty the iframe and resend it to the API to be rendered again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Oscar Jara's answer to a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658546/4669143

If the iframe origin in the same as the enclosing site's origin, you should be able to do it without violating the cross-domain policy.  Otherwise, it won't work.

He includes a working fiddle.