# How to delete HTML Elements in an iFrame using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame and a div with content in it. I want to delete the div via JavaScript, is that possible and how could I do that?

I don't want to just not display it (eg. `display: none` via CSS) but remove it from the HTML of the site. I have basic knowledge of JavaScript but don't have any experience working with an iFrame.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong. Also remember that you CANNOT modify the content of an iframe which exists on a different host / domain to the parent page - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
$("#iFrameId").contents().find("#yourDiv").empty();
```

It is better to use `remove()`

example: `$("#iFrameId").contents().find("#yourDiv").remove();`

**Explanation**

`empty()` will remove all the contents of the selection.

`remove()` will remove the selection and its contents and all the event handlers associated with it.

For reference:

1. http://api.jquery.com/remove/
2. http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: I understand it as it should be `remove()` not `empty()`, but i'm not sure what is expected behaviour

Comment: Yes, remove() is a better option than empty() in this case!! Thankzz!!

Comment: I have tried this and it worked for a normal "iframe" but not with a spreadshirt shop integration. You can view an example shop at: https://developer.spreadshirt.net/display/spreadShop/SpreadShop-Our+new+Partner+Shopsystem scroll down at Out of the Box Shop Example. I just want to remove the footer, but when i use $("#footer").remove(); nothing happens.

Comment: When i try $("#footer").remove(); online at their site (https://developer.spreadshirt.net/display/spreadShop/SpreadShop-Our+new+Partner+Shopsystem) it removes the footer. But not when i try it locally. I'm testing it locally but i'm online and i can't remove the footer. Is it because i test it "locally" or it's because of their script which is loading and maybe i have to execute the remove script after their script?

Comment: When i test the site local and than add the code in the firebug console i can remove the footer but when i try it in the HTML document i can't remove the footer. I've tested it live on my server and there's the same problem code written in the console no problem, code in html executed no chance to remove the footer. So what now? I've tried to combine the jquery .ready function but nothing. Why is the console approach working and not the code in the html?

Comment: I think that it doesn't worl because the "Domains, protocols and ports must match.". Please have a look at the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Please also refer to this solution [same origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: Please also refer to this SO Solution [ways to circumvent same origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:-

```
frame.removeChild(//pass div id here);
```