# how can i use javascript to remove iframe's html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to remove iframe's content but keep the "iframe tag" unchanged
like:

```
<iframe>
    <html>
    ...
    </html>
</iframe>
```

change to

```
<iframe>
</iframe>
```

I tried this:

```
var frame_node = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
frame_node.removeChild(frame_node.firstChild);
```

But I got an error: frame_node.firstChild is not an object

So how to do this?
thx

---

got the answer:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.doc‌​ument.getElementsByT‌​agName("html")[0].re‌​move();
```

Comment: Are you asking about HTML inside the iframe tags in the source, or inside the iframe content itself?

Comment: can u refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808185/how-to-delete-html-elements-in-an-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara inside the iframe content itself, not from src

Comment: @Varun Sreedharan thanks! it works! i use this: `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].remove();` so... should I remove the question ?