# Angular - How to remove elements from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, angular5

I'm trying to remove the  and  tags of the iFrame in Angular 5. However everything i've found on stackoverflow or other sites doesn't work and i'd assume it's slightly different in angular. I can't figure out how to have this execute correctly and can't seem to using the iframe which i use document.getElementById("twitch-frame"); can't use that variable to get elements inside of the iframe or the like.

Any and all help that'd point to what the issue is/ how i can do this would be very greatly appreciated because it doesn't seem to make sense as to why I can't hit the elements using corrects class names or tag names.

[Source of the website i'm working in](https://github.com/buffet-time/themeathon.com/tree/master/src/app/components) ( In the Stream component html/ ts/ css )

Comment: It is impossible unless you change the content of iframe source

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808185/how-to-delete-html-elements-in-an-iframe-using-javascript

This question seems to contradict that. Though this wasn't working either. And it doesn't make sense why you wouldnt be able to seeing as you can get the elements inside of the iframe so normal dom manipulation should still apply to it.