# Disable/Hide download button in iframe on default PDF Viewer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, iframe

i am using `#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0` in iframe url for disabling toolbar but in Mozzila it doesn't work. I tryed to import javascript into iframe, but the same result....
iframe:

```
<iframe ?wmode="transparent" type="application/pdf" id="iframe" src="'.$url.'#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="685"></iframe>
```

used js:

```
jQuery('#iframe').load(function(){
    jQuery('#iframe').contents().find("#toolbarViewerRight").hide();
});
```

Any idea, how can i disable/remove/hide this toolbar or only download button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot modify content of iframe, what is wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong)

Comment: it doesn=t work for me. I try to hide and remove, but no change... It can be pdf viewer default option, which prevent me to remove/hide toolbarViewerRight

Answer (score 31):

Use #toolbar=0 after your .pdf file name in src

```
<iframe src="your-pdf-name.pdf#toolbar=0"></iframe>
```

Comment: this helped me, I was just curious if this, or other options are documented somewhere?

Comment: toolbar=0 will remove all the options. What if I only want to hide download and print options ?

Comment: @sunny any luck on this

Comment: @Mohit: I didn't get a workaround as far as I remember

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
<iframe src="kd/kd.pdf?page=hsn#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="1000" id="iframe11">
</iframe>
```

Comment: toolbar=0 will remove all the options. What if I only want to hide download and print options ?

Comment: same issue with me. Is there any option/s to disable just few options from toolbar ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using embed tag instead iframe tag, like this:

```
<embed src="http://host/yourpdf.pdf#toolbar=0" style="width:600px; height:500px;">
```