# How can we disable the print and save options in pdf?

Tags: browser

I used Iframe in

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="{self.href}#toolbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500">
```

it will hide toolbar from google chrome but not from mozila firefox.how to hide toolbar from firefox

Comment: Please share printscrn of the page.

Comment: This depends on the PDF viewer the client uses. This has neither to do with HTML, CSS or JS nor is there an option on the `iframe` element to disable anything in a third-party plugin. For example Chromium-based browsers use [PDFium](https://opensource.google.com/projects/pdfium) per default. (see chrome://credits/ for as list of internally used software)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable/Hide download button in iframe on default PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586093/disable-hide-download-button-in-iframe-on-default-pdf-viewer)

Comment: More Like Browser Dependent issue.

Comment: `#toolbar=0` is probably not supported by all PDF viewers, and even if no toolbar is visible, I can still use the save and print options from the context menu

Comment: @deepeshkumar I want to hide toolbar from mozila firefox