# Disable right-button in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, iframe, frontend

I am using vue and JavaScript for the implementation of the frontend part of a web platform. I have implemented the display of a pdf using the iframe component, and I would like to be able to disable the right click option so that the document cannot be downloaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable/Hide download button in iframe on default PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586093/disable-hide-download-button-in-iframe-on-default-pdf-viewer)

Comment: This answer is from 5 years ago, it does not currently answer the question, that is why I have opened a new thread

Comment: For anyone else landing here and looking for an answer, you can add an empty event listener for contextmenu with the prevent modifier on the element you don't want right-clicked on:

`<div @contextmenu.prevent>...</div>`