# How to remove download and print options when displaying pdf in iframe

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

when I display a `pdf` file in `iframe`, I want the toolbar to be displayed, but it does not have `download` and `print` options, please guide me.
Finally, I want to have the toolbar, but without download and print options

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <iframe src="https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
    style="
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  "
  width="100%" height="100%" type='application/pdf' >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content of an iframe is from a different domain than the parent page, it is not possible to access and edit it directly. Web browsers impose this limitation, known as the Same-Origin Policy, for security concerns.

you can hide the toolbar but not only print and download buttons.

[Previous Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586093/disable-hide-download-button-in-iframe-on-default-pdf-viewer)

Answer (score 0):

The use of the Adobe Signal Toolbar=0 should be considered like other features as an "Advisory Hint" to the downloaded PDF file in the clients editor.

It does not have to be honoured by Adobe Plugin (or any other browser PDF viewer) as the toolbar is often needed for Read Aloud or many other functions here showing Adobe Sign In.

**In some simpler Chrome cases** it may be removed from the view area but the user can switch it back on in different ways.

[image]

[image]

Removing the Toolbar is anti-social (even in Kiosks where it's intended for banner free presentations) as it disadvantages those that need to see the Read Aloud or other functions such as kiosk printing.

[image]

Here in Chromium MS Edge powered by Acrobat the iframe carrier set the toolbar to 0 (it functioned) HOWEVER user just has to press F8 for the Main toolbar to be made visible again. Some browser PDF viewers will simply ignore the Toolbar directive as unnecessary interference.

[image]

### Or they can make it smaller

[image]