# Remove target="_blank" from an iframe after its loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to remove the target="_blank" attribute from links inside the html loaded by an iframe.
How can i do this after the loading of all the sections?
this is the link https://nnd9wjqxzdcckxxewmrb6w-on.drv.tw/html/prova.html

this is the code of the page before the loading.

```html
<iframe src="https://schneider-electric.app.box.com/embed/s/es48mnabibdc6rmdwr6ukanv36z0f3zo? 
    sortColumn=date&view=list" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Guess what, not going to happen since it is probably a different origin. If it is a same origin, then you can do something.... So is it the same domain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong

Comment: And there's probably a better alternative to achieve what you want to do instead of modifying iframe content

Comment: [link](https://nnd9wjqxzdcckxxewmrb6w-on.drv.tw/html/prova.html) can you see with this link? @epascarello

Comment: You will need server side code to change stuff from a different domain.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: so i cannot do my request, ok thank you... and if i want to open in the fullscreen mode the iframe when the page is loaded? is the same issue? thank you a lot @epascarello