# How to get html element from iframe using javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I wanted to hide some html part of iframe which is added on my Sharepoint page.
I am not able to object using javascript/jquery.
Is there any way to get it.

Note: I have nested iframe elements

Comment: You cannot access or modify the contents of an iframe from the parent page.

Comment: [Hey take a look at this . This should help you ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658011/cannot-modify-content-of-iframe-what-is-wrong)

Comment: Could you show us your code samples? That way, we can take a good look at your problem and provide you with better solutions.

Comment: Actually I am using visio web part in Sharepoint online modern page,where internally it laod the visio file in iframe.When I debug the code I found that there are nested iframes.I could able to get the iframe element at 3rd level,but I am not able to get the html of 3rd Iframe using javascript as mentioned in the blog shared by sanket

Comment: I cant share the code samples